# Javascript me esta imprimiendo mas numeros de lo que hay en el div

Tags: javascript, css, html5, latex, impresion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![    // metodo del boton
funtion iniciar(){

```
document.querySelector("#imprimir").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var div = document.querySelector("#pantalla");
    imprimirElemento(div);
  });
```

}

// Funcion que imprime el pdf

function imprimirElemento(elemento){

```
    var ventana = window.open('', 'popimpr');
    ventana.document.write(elemento.innerHTML);
    ventana.document.close();
    ventana.focus();
    ventana.print();
    ventana.close();
return true;
```

}
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSICq.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSICq.png)

```
introducir el código aquí
 // Salto de linea
            let salto = document.createElement("div");
            let texto_vacio = document.createTextNode("\\(\\)");
            salto.appendChild(texto_vacio);
            let pantalla_salto = document.getElementById("pantalla");
            pantalla_salto.appendChild(salto);
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'unique-id']);

            // ejercicio 
            let etiqueta_ejercicio = document.createElement("div");
            let etiqueta_contenido = document.createTextNode("\\(" + contador + ") \\frac{" + numUno + "}{" + denUno + "} * \\frac{" + numDos + "}{" + denDos + "}\\)");
            etiqueta_ejercicio.appendChild(etiqueta_contenido);
            let pantalla_ejercicio = document.getElementById("pantalla");
            pantalla_ejercicio.appendChild(etiqueta_ejercicio);
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, 'unique-id']);
```

//** ojo estoy dando un salto de linea con un div aunque se que se puede hacer de otra manera pero el resultado es el mismo*//

Comment: tu pregunta no es clara, ¿puedes indicar que es lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Ya la arregle Fernando lo quiero es imprimir lo que esta en pantalla del imagen pero si te fija al lado donde esta saliendo el pdf me esta agregando mas numeros

Comment: Muestra tu código donde tienes las fracciones

Comment: Ayuda con esto por favor que mi programa no sirve si no puedo imprimir correctamente

Answer (score 0):

```
    introducir el código aquí


>Encontre una solución para mi problema hice lo siguiente:

>en el css del programa oculte todo lo que no queria que se viera en la >impresion y puse visible la pantalla donde estaban los ejercicios luego en javascript utilice el metodo window.print() y  listo:

    



@media print{
    #menu-1{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
    #menu-2{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
    #menu-3{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
    #menu-4{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
    #menu-5{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
    #pantalla1{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none;
    }

    #menos{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #cantidad{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #mas{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #titulo{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #generar{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #imprimir{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #menu-5{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    #footer{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: none; 
    }
    
    
    
    #pantalla {

        margin-top: 5px;
        visibility: visible;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: hidden;

    }
}

> en  javascript :
function ImprimirPdf(){
window.print();
}
```